# Can I initiate an automatic download of a csv and display text on a page at the same time?

Tags: php

I'm imagining a user going to page and having a download automatically initiate. The page they visit will have instructions on what to do with the file. Right now, the text of the page is being included in the csv file instead of echoing to the page. Can this even be down in one script? Here is my code...

```
<?php
function databaseConnection() {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=IP ; Database=database",'user','password');
    return $conn;
}
function getStudents() {
    global $conn;
    $studentsql =
        "SQL query";
    $studentquery = $conn->prepare($studentsql);
    $studentquery->execute();
    $studentarray = array();
    while ($studentrow = $studentquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $studentarray[] = $studentrow;
    }
    return $studentarray;
}
function createFile($fileheader,$filebody) {
    $file = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
    fputcsv($file, $fileheader);
    foreach ($filebody as $key => $students) {
        fputcsv($file, $students); 
    }
    rewind($file);
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
    fpassthru($file);
    fclose($file);
}

$conn = databaseConnection();

$fileheader = array("header1","header2");

createFile($fileheader, getStudents());

$conn = null;

echo "<p>The file has automatically downloaded and was placed in your downloads folder.</p>
<p>Double clicking the file will automatically open it in Excel. You should then go to File | Save As <br>
and choose a different name and save it as an excel file by choosing .xlsx as the file type.";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Display the result on the page and then redirect to the file download.
2. Use Javascript, load the data through an AJAX request, display it on the page and redirect to a [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).